# How to PreSign a transaction

Tags: smart-contract, on-chain, time, submission

im trying to figure out how to sign a smart contract (SC) and have it put on-chain, where it waits until its validation logic returns True.

Edit 1:

To clarify what I mean by signing is the private key signature. The purpose would be to have the user sign the contract once and after X years the contract is activated. The user should not be able to Sign again after this point as the user is believed to have died and the address locked. At this point, the contract act as a last will and testament, sending the ada balance to the beneficiary.

Comment: what do you mean by "sign" a smart contract?

Comment: When you use nami or another wallet the user should input their password only once. If its correct the private key signature is applied. this should only happen once as the validation logic of the contract is initially False, and only becomes True once the contract should be run. This means that the contract will also stay on chain.

Answer (score 1):

Scripts on the ledger are passive, they do not act unless a party sends a transaction that propagates the state of the script.

If I understand correctly, you want a vesting scheme, this is possible. Have a look at [(1)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ae7U_yKIQ0Y).